# Ansible collection usage

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use Ansible Collection for example the [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/announcing-nginx-core-collection-ansible/) one.

The directory tree structure looks like this:

```
    ├── ansible_collections
    │   └── nginxinc
    │       └── nginx_core
    │           ├── CHANGELOG.md
.......
    │           ├── README.md
    │           └── roles
    │               ├── nginx
    │               │   ├── tasks
    │               │   │   ├── amplify
    │               │   │   ├── config
    │               │   │   ├── keys
    │               │   │   ├── main.yml
    │               │   │   ├── modules
    │               │   │   ├── opensource
    │               │   │   │   └── install-debian.yml
    │               │   │   └── unit
    ....
        ├── hosts
        └── site.yaml
```

the `site.yaml` file I wrote is:

```
- name: Demo
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: test
    include_role:
      name: nginxinc.nginx_core.nginx
      tasks_from: install-debian
```

I am trying to run the task `install-debian` from the role nginx.

I run the playbook:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yaml`

I get this error:

`ERROR! the role 'nginxinc.nginx_core.nginx' was not found.....`

I need help on how I should fix the `site.yaml` file

Comment: `nginxinc.nginx_core.nginx` is not a role, it is a collection. What are you trying to do, since NGINX's collection can do multiple things like installing NGINX, configuring it, ...

Comment: I am trying to understand how to correctly call a  task in a role that belongs to a  collection. I am migrating my project from role to collection

Comment: I have clarified what I am trying to achieve in the question @β.εηοιτ.βε

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should just install the Nginx collection with the following command, [as explained here](https://github.com/nginxinc/ansible-collection-nginx#ansible-galaxy):

```
ansible-galaxy collection install nginxinc.nginx_core
```

It should install it in `~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/nginxinc/nginx_core/`. Then create a playbook following [these examples](https://github.com/nginxinc/ansible-collection-nginx/tree/main/playbooks) and the [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html#using-collections-in-playbooks):

```
---
- hosts: all
  collections:
    - nginxinc.nginx_core
  roles:
    - role: nginx
```

Finally run your playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts my_nginx_playbook.yaml
```

It'll pick the Debian version for you if your host is Debian.

Answer (score 1):

I regret to say that this is not working for me. this gives the impression that collections_paths is not used.

#### ansible --version

ansible 2.9.17

#### ansible-config view

```
[defaults]
inventory=/usr/local/ansible-admin/my_hosts
roles_path=/usr/local/galaxy-roles:./roles
collections_paths=/usr/local/ansible_collections
log_path=./ansible.log
```

the collections are installed in the /usr/local/ansible_collections folder:

#### tree -L 2 /usr/local/ansible_collections/nginxinc/

```
/usr/local/ansible_collections/nginxinc/
└── nginx_core
    ├── CHANGELOG.md
    ├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
    ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
    ├── docs
    ├── FILES.json
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── MANIFEST.json
    ├── playbooks
    ├── plugins
    ├── README.md
    └── roles
```

here is the very basic content of the playbook:

#### cat playbooks/nginx_core.yml

```
- name: Test collection ansible with nginxinc
 hosts: "{{ target }}"
  collections:
    - nginxinc.nginx_core
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: nginx
```

we get the following error message when it is launched:

#### ansible-playbook playbooks/nginx_core.yml --extra-vars target=myvm.mydomain.org

```
ERROR! the role 'nginx' was not found in nginxinc.nginx_core:ansible.legacy:/usr/local/ansible-admin/playbooks/roles:/usr/local/galaxy-roles:/usr/local/ansible-admin/roles:/usr/local/ansible-admin/playbooks
```

it doesn't find the role in the collections, and worse, it doesn't say that it looked in the collections_path...

But here is a solution that works, but it is very very ugly: add the nginx role of the collection in roles_path!

```
roles_path=/usr/local/galaxy-roles:./roles:/usr/local/ansible_collections/nginxinc/nginx_core/roles
```

warning: this is obviously a misuse of the ansible collections!

any help would be appreciated.

Ernest.